# What is the probability that this harmonic series with randomly chosen signs will converge?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Suppose we fix $p$ between $0$ and $1$ (without loss of generalization, we can assume $p \leq 1/2$). Then suppose we form the series $\sum_n a_n / n$ where the $a_n$ are independent random variables and each $a_n$ equals $1$ with probability $p$ and equals $-1$ with probability $1-p$. (Hence why we can assume $p \leq 1/2$.) What is the probability that this series converges, as a function of $p$? Clearly if the series diverges with probability 1 for $p = 1/2$ then it always diverges with probability $1$ for any $p$, so perhaps the case $p=1/2$ is the most interesting. (However, if other values of $p$ give non-zero probability of convergence that would also obviously be interesting.)

Comment: This will clear everything up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thanks! That definitely settles the case of $p = 1/2$. I'm currently going over the theorem to see if it determines the case $p \neq 1/2$, and also if the series can thus be divergent, then whether the probability of convergence is always 0. If you're willing to help a bit more, I would gladly up-vote and accept your answer for general $p$. It seems like you have already found the crucial piece to this puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the comment by Byron and your response to it: The theorem that Byron pointed to clears up not only the case $p=1/2$ but also all other cases. Condition II of the theorem, that the expected values of $Y_n=X_n1_{\{|X_n|\le A\}}$ converge for some $A\gt0$, is not fulfilled, since for any $A\gt0$ the indicator variable eventually becomes unity, so we have $Y_n=X_n$ for sufficiently large $n$, and the expected value of $X_n$ is $(2p-1)/n$, so for large $n$ this series that would have to converge is a multiple of the harmonic series (which diverges).

Comment: Thanks, it takes me a while to go through new math but this clears it up. I find it interesting that "intuitively" the series would have to diverge for $p \neq 1/2$, since it should be unavoidably biased toward a multiple of the harmonic series, which diverges.

Answer (score 10):

Random harmonic series - [A little self promotion.](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/people/schmu/preprints/rhs.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting read. =)

Comment: Ah, I should have remembered and mentioned that -- I remember I enjoyed it when I read it :-)

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the kind words!

Comment: I'm actually rereading it now :-)